# How can I exclude certain directories from a VSTS build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build definition that needs to build a number of related solutions, so the build definition has (in YAML)

```
variables:
  build.Configuration: 'Release'
steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: Build solution **/*Lumen*.sln
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*Lumen*.sln'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: '$(build.Configuration)'
```

But this builds too much; specifically, it builds solutions under the Archive directory. Is there a way to specify the solution input that says "all directories *except* the Archive directory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the solution option for MSBuild task input is only used for specifying the **included patterns**, not exclude patterns. So you can not specify exclude patterns in an MSBuild task for now.

But I created an issue, *[Enable to specify ExcludePatterns, for solutions in a VS build task and MSBuild task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8144)* which suggest to enable specifying exclude patterns for a MSBuild task and VS Build task. You can follow up there.